# Would there be any advantage to using a linear accelerator in a PET scanner, rather than a cyclotron?

Tags: particle-physics

Does it manage to create radioactive isotopes more quickly than a cyclotron would?

I understand that space and cost make cyclotrons the obvious choice, but I mean in a hypothetical scenario, would there be anything at all to make a linear accelerator the better choice?

Comment: (1) You don't use them in a PET scanner, you use the accelerators to make the appropriate isotopes for introduction into the body. (2)  You need a useful fluence of protons in a short period, so you need high flux. Cyclotrons are much better at that than linacs.